# How to Auto adjust Y-axis Scale, how to show only 2 digits on Y-axis Double and more

Tags: mschart

For the last couple of days im trying to use MS-chart control to chart StockData (1 min interval, candlestock) which i have on my sql server. i thought its going to be easy... but now im at a point where im gonna cry soon.

im having so many problems if anyone can solve any he will be blesses for ever:
// my code is in the bottom, i may have done some fatal mistakes

1. whenever i change

   ```
   series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
   ```

   the scroll bar doesnt work properly anymore, i cannot drag it anymore, i can however
   point somewhere on the scroll bar and it will take me there, but i cannot smoothly drag it as i could when it was plain int index.
2. where i scroll through the different hrs(minute by minute) im having serious problems
   with Y-axis, i set the maximum and minimum on the begining but its not very effective
   as u scroll through the chart.
3. for each point i set (in the populating loop)

   ```
   series.Points[index]["PriceUpColor"] = "Green";
   series.Points[index]["PriceDownColor"] = "Red";
   ```

   but all the candles turned out red regardless.
4. i have a button when it clicked i want the chart to be populated then, this does not
   work, its only works if i put my code under form_load
5. i set the axis lbl

   ```
   chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm";
   ```

   is this the correct code?
6. when i have float values (example:26.52), but when i put those values in the
   series.Points.AddXY, the result on the chars will be 26.5273287623 which of course doesnt help, i tried many diffrent solutions (casting, removing the digits my self etc) 
   but couldnt find a solution

Lastly 
here is my code, i put a chart on my form and i call this function to change the chart setting and populate i t(am i already doing wrong?)

I realize that this is quite long, what can i say, Thank you for your help! (all help is welcome!)

```
private void MyChart(Chart chart1, DailyBarData dbb)
```

-> getting a chart component and dailybardata, and theoretically should populate the chart accordingly
-> iv insert some random data as well

```
    {

        int viewSize = 30;     
        chart1.Series.Clear();        
        var series = chart1.Series.Add("Price");
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;       
        series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
        series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;                            
        DateTime date = dbb.Bars[0].time.AddMinutes (1); //getting the first minute
        double viewdistanceDouble = date.AddMinutes(viewSize).ToOADate(); // getting the initital X loc - im guessing this is not good
        double startdateDouble = date.ToOADate();
        double maxy = 0; //minmax values for the chart
        double miny = 10000000;
        for (int index = 0; index < dbb.Count()-1; index++)
        {          


            BarData b = dbb.Bars[index];
            series.Points.AddXY(
               b.time,                // X value is a date
         b.TwoDigits (b.High),    // High Y value - is originally a float, here i mult by 100, cast to int then double then divide by 100
                                    //and gets the exact same result..... i realize this is unneeded but i cant solve it
               b.TwoDigits(b.Low),    // Low Y value
          b.TwoDigits(b.Open),    // Open Y value
         b.TwoDigits(b.Close));    // Close Y value


            if (b.Low < miny) miny = b.Low;
            if (b.High > maxy) maxy = b.High;



            // u can use this code instead, however those values are ints and not floats which is half of the problem
            // with this values i get less problems
            //series.Points.AddXY(
            //    date,                // X value is a date
            //    rnd.Next(40, 50),    // High Y value
            //    rnd.Next(10, 20),    // Low Y value
            //    rnd.Next(20, 40),    // Open Y value
            //    rnd.Next(20, 40));    // Close Y value
            //date = date.AddMinutes(1);


            series.Points[index]["PriceUpColor"] = "Green"; // this code have unclear effects as it always red
            series.Points[index]["PriceDownColor"] = "Red";
            series.Points[index].Color = Color.Black;
            series.Points[index].BorderColor = Color.Black;

        }

        var chartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea];        
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm";
        chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 5;
        chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(startdateDouble, viewdistanceDouble); //starting scale , rarly works    
        chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = viewSize;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
        chartArea.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
        chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = maxy ; //by the values found on the loop, not good i want it to be automated when u scroll
        chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = miny;


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is known, but I don't know if it can be fixed either.
2. Maybe you should give more details?
3. Maybe you should show where you declare PriceUpColor and PriceDown.
4. "series.Points.AddXY(b.time" is it a plain DateTime? have you tried using.ToOADate() instead?.
5. I'd say it is correct.
6. Maybe it is a precission issue because of casting, as the MS Chart controls work with doubles.

EDIT: For 1 you can try

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
```

Or some other type.

Comment: about 3, its was my mistake, i blamed the chart but it was me after all, so thats solved! about 1: further more your tip does infact make it possible to move the slider, but il have to find the correct value, because it completly distored the X-axis for some reason, but this looks to me as a solution. about 2: lets say i have values from

Comment: about 3, its was my mistake, i blamed the chart but it was me after all, so thats solved! about 1: further more your tip does infact make it possible to move the slider, but il have to find the correct value, because it completly distored the X-axis for some reason, but this looks to me as a solution. about 2: lets say i have values from 1-2 the first 30 candles are between 1.10-1.30 so i set the y axis min max to those values, when u further scroll ovcourse the x values will change >1.30 but the yaxis min max is stil as it were defined initially.

Comment: about 4: i tried using Tooadate but in all truth i do not remember the result, it didnt help me that i know for sure. i will try everything again, and post if il find an answer. thank you for your time and help!

Comment: chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds; this solves 1!!!! (the distortion ihad was again due to my own fault...)

Comment: For item #6, something like `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.0}"` helps clean this up some.